# Asynchronous module completed while another operation is pending

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am connecting to the Quickbooks api, download the employees inforamtion and saving it to my local database.  I am using angularjs, webapi to accomplish this. I am  getting the following error when I am saving the info to database. I do see all the functions have async and await. Can some body please help me why I am getting this error.

Error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

Problem is happening in the below pasted piece of code:

```
 var candidate = await CandidateLoginBL.AddCandidateByEmployeeAsync(new CandidateLoginBO()
                        {
                            FirstName = e.GivenName,
                            MiddleName = e.MiddleName,
                            LastName = e.FamilyName
          });
                        }
                    });
```

The full flow is as follows :

js :

```
QuickbookModule.factory('QuickbookService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
 getQuickbooksSync: function () {
            return $http({
                url: '/api/QuickbookService/syncQuickbooks',
                method: 'GET',
                params: { IdCompany: sessionStorage.CID }
            });
        }
```

API Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("syncQuickbooks")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> syncQuickbooks(int IdCompany)
        {
          var result = await QuickbooksBL.FullQuickbooksSync(IdCompany);
          return Ok(result);
        }
```

QuickbooksBL :

```
     public static async Task<List<IncompleteEmp>> FullQuickbooksSync(int IdCompany)
            {return await SyncronizeEmps(IdCompany); }

        public static async Task<List<IncompleteEmp>> SyncronizeEmps(int companyId)
            {                   
                   ......      
                    List<EmployeeBO> empList = new List<EmployeeBO>();
                    await AddToHumanEfits(companyId, inQBEmpsInfo);                       ....    
                }
                           return IncompleteEmps;
            }


         public static async Task AddToHumanEfits(int companyId, List<EmployeeQbOnlineBO> qbEmpsList)
            {                
                  ....
                    qbEmpsList.ForEach(async e =>
                    {  

                            // Add a record into Candidate Login. 

                      var candidate = await CandidateLoginBL.AddCandidateByEmployeeAsync(new CandidateLoginBO()
                        {
                            FirstName = e.GivenName,
                            MiddleName = e.MiddleName,
                            LastName = e.FamilyName              });
                        }
                    });    
            }
```

CandidateContactBL :

```
 public static async Task<CandidateLoginBO> AddCandidateByEmployeeAsync(CandidateLoginBO model)
        {
            return await CandidateLoginDAL.AddCandidateByEmployeeAsync(model);
        }
```

CandidateContactDAL :

```
public static async Task<CandidateLoginBO> AddCandidateByEmployeeAsync(CandidateLoginBO model)
        {
            CandidateLoginBO candidate = new CandidateLoginBO();

                candidate = await GetByUserNameAsync(new CandidateLoginBO() { Email = model.Email });                        candidate = await AddEmployeeAsync(model);                   
            return candidate;
        }
```

Comment: Can't you narrow the problem down to a smaller code example?

Comment: sure. the problem is happening in the // Add a record into Candidate Login.  section. I add the code to show the full flow.

Comment: So why do we need all the other code? Strip it back until you have a minimal code snippet that still presents the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of error is commonly caused by `async void`. And I see one right here:

```
qbEmpsList.ForEach(async e =>
{
  ...
});
```

You'd probably want to make this into a regular `foreach`:

```
foreach (var e in qbEmpsList)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: so there is a problem with async void ? If you have blogged about it please send me the link

Comment: @joedotnot: My [article that introduced the phrase "avoid `async void`"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) references this problem: "One subtle trap is passing an async lambda to a method taking an Action parameter; in this case, the async lambda returns void and inherits all the problems of async void methods."